# How to install Rhythmbox Spotify plugin?

Tags: rhythmbox, plugins, spotify

Is there an easy way to install the Spotify plugin for Rhythmbox in Ubuntu 12.04?

I can only find links to recompile Rhythmbox completely and the instructions aren't very clear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are referring to [this Rhythmbox Spotify plugin](https://github.com/ivankelly/Rhythmbox-Spotify-Plugin), then I'm afraid the answer is no, there isn't a way to install it other [than building the whole of Rhythmbox with it](http://web.archive.org/web/20100110051000/http://wiki.bleurgh.com/RhythmboxSpotify).

Also notice that the code for that plugin hasn't been touched for 3 years, so it's likely that no longer works with the current Rhythmbox code.

All in all, my suggestion would be to stay away from that plugin and use the native Spotify client instead.