# How do I import a Rhythmbox playlist into Spotify?

Tags: rhythmbox, spotify, playlists

I have some playlists on Rhythmbox that I would like to import in Spotify but I could not find a way.

There's this website called [Ivy](http://www.ivyishere.org/) that lets you import platlists that are in CSV files or in iTunes' format (whatever format that is), but it does not support importing playlists in .pls format. I also could not find a way to convert a .pls file to .csv.

Is there a way to copy a playlist from Rhythmbox to Spotify?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/135072/how-to-install-rhythmbox-spotify-plugin

Comment: @Nick I did see this thread before but it is of no help since it seems that the spotify plug in has not been supported for a while now, so the plugin does not seem to be an option.

Answer (score 0):

To get your playlists into Spotify you need the following:

1. your playlist in `m3u` format
2. a [Spotify client](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7489/how-to-get-the-native-version-of-spotify-running) installed within Ubuntu (not the web-page)

Right click the Rhythmbox playlist and save as a file.

[image: pic]

Make sure you change the file name to have a `m3u` extension and you choose the m3u format as shown.

Next visit the following website:

- http://spotmysongs.com/

Looking at the help on the site - this website appears to be run by the folks of spotify themselves, so it looks fairly authentic

Click the <kbd>choose file</kbd> on the website and navigate to your `m3u` file.

Then click <kbd>spot my songs</kbd>

Finally fire-up your spotify client and ensure your client and the *spotmysongs* webpage are side-by side.  Drag-and-drop your new playlist into spotify

[image]

Enjoy playing your new rhythmbox-to-spotify playlist

Comment: Hmmm... when I click on spot my songs in chromium the process never finishes and I get an error page that says that the operation timed out. When I try it in firefox, it takes me back to the original page, it doesn't show me the page that says "Your Own Spotifylist" in your animation.

Comment: Try with a dummy playlist first with a couple of songs - once you've confirmed that is working, try with slightly larger playlists.  The site is in beta - you may have found a bug with your particular playlist.  BTW  - I used chrome - not chromium in the picture.